# How to display eloquent query into view blade?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am querying a list of staffs from 'itemregistration' table with the eloquent relationship with 'section' table. But I cannot display the information from section table to the view blade.

My controller get the query as follows:

```
  $itemregistrations = Itemregistration::with('section')->get();
```

When I check the array with:

```
 dd($itemregistrations->toArray());
```

I get this result:

```
 0 => array:133 [▼
"ItemRegistrationID" => 1
"RegistrationDate" => "2005-12-01"
"SectionID" => 12
"name" => "A SANTESH"
"section" => array:2 [ …2]
]
```

The section array should contain 'SectionID' and 'sectionname' fields.

If I check with 
    dd($itemregistration);

it produce

```
 Collection {#1948 ▼
 #items: array:1125 [▼
 0 => Itemregistration {#1990 ▼
  #primaryKey: "ItemRegistrationID"
  #hidden: array:1 [ …1]
  +timestamps: false
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: null
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:133 [ …133]
  #original: array:133 [ …133]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:1 [ …1]
  #touches: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [ …1]
```

I want to display the result in the blade but failed to fetch the section array value:

```
 @foreach($itemregistrations as $index => $value)                                                                
    <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $value->section->sectionname }}</td>
 @endforeach
```

I also tried:

```
 @foreach($itemregistrations as $index => $value)                                                                
    <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
    @foreach($value as $section => $val) 
     <td>{{ $val->sectionname }}</td>
    @endforeach 
 @endforeach
```

But also failed. The error appears is "Trying to get property of non-object".

I tried to see the values contained in the collection through this code:

```
    @foreach ($itemregistrations as $item)
     <tr>
       <td>{{ $item }}</td>
       <td>{{ $item->section }}</td>                             
     </tr>
    @endforeach
```

And it shows this value in this format:

```
{"ItemRegistrationID":1,"name":"A Santesh"{"SectionID":12,"sectionname":"E"}}
```

If I show the result with this:
        @foreach ($itemregistrations as $item)
         
           {{ $item->name }}
         
        @endforeach

I can get the name list but to get the sectionname with this

```
    @foreach ($itemregistrations as $item)
     <tr>
       <td>{{ $item->section->sectionname }}</td>                           
     </tr>
    @endforeach
```

It shows error "Trying to get property of non-object ". I dont understand why I can't get the section values.

My section model:

```
  class Section extends Authenticatable
{
protected $table = 'sections';
protected  $primaryKey = 'SectionID';
 /**
 * Get the user that have agama.
 */
public function itemregistrations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Itemregistration', 'SectionID', 'ItemregistrationID');
}

}
```

Itemregistration model:

```
  class Itemregistration extends Model 
{
protected  $primaryKey = 'ItemRegistrationID';

/*
 * Get all of the owning models.
 */

public function section()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Section', 'SectionID');

}
```

How to get display the query with section array values?

Comment: I had edited my question and add some clues to identify the error. Can anyone help me figure out what missing in my code? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for others' help with my question.

I had configured the right syntax to get to the values of sectionname in section array. I don't know why I can't use -> helper to get to the values. I tried the following syntax and it can fetch the values in blade view.

```
 @foreach ($itemregistrations as $item)
 <tr>
   <td>{{ $item->name }}</td> //also can <td>{{ $item['name'] }}</td>
   <td>{{ $item['section]['sectionname'] }}</td>                             
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with the following code:

```
@foreach($itemregistrations as $index => $value)
  <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
  @foreach($value->section as $section) 
    <td>{{ $section->sectionname }}</td>
  @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

Comment: owh..why need if else here?

Comment: also get the same error and it shows the error at --> <td>{{ $section->sectionname }}</td>

Comment: yes..but it shows the same error at section->sectionname

Comment: I think the problem in your relation. How do you get that array? Your relation is one to one. You have to fix the relation otherwise you will get a single item in section relation.

Comment: my relation one to many..itemregistration can have one section but one section can belong to many itemregistration. I am new to eloquent relation so I did that according to samples available in tutorials

Comment: I see.. Your itemregistration contains only one section and the relation also ok. you will get only one section from itemregistration. You can get multiple itemregistration from section object. So what's the point to loop over section since one itemregistration contains only one section? what you exactly want to show in your blade template?

Comment: section values included in other tables grabbed using relation with itemregistration. I want to display the section values but failed. I used relation instead of raw sql queries to improve speed performance

Comment: I put the collection content of itemregistration in the question

Answer (score 1):

I assume, that `@foreach` call `toArray()` on `Collection`, so then you should handle your data as named array, so try this:

```
@foreach($itemregistrations as $index => $value)                                                                
  <td>{{ $value['name'] }}</td>
  @foreach($value['section'] as $section => $val) 
    <td>{{ $val['sectionname'] }}</td>
  @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

Comment: there is error says "Illegal string offset 'sectionname'"

Comment: Don't you have typo in this sectionname? Please check it

Comment: the sectionname is the right field name. I found the solution as answered below. maybe you have an explaination to it..I am not really understand it but I just tried possible ways and it worked.